# Проверить, является ли введенная строка палиндромом, игнорируя пробелы и регистр

Tags: python

Я только начала изучать Python, и не все понятно.

Написала такое решение:

### Первое решение

```
import sys

my_str = str(sys.argv[1])
my_str = my_str.lower()


rev_str = reversed(my_str)

if list(my_str) == list(rev_str):
   print("YES")
else:
   print("NO")
```

Все хорошо работает до момента, когда строка содержит пробелы. Что нужно изменить, чтобы заработало и с пробелами тоже?

### Второй вариант

Проблема в том что всегда выдает значение `ДА`, где косяк?

```
import sys

s = str(sys.argv[1])
s = s.lower()
s = s.split()
s_ = ''

l = len(s_)
i = 0
f = 1
while i < l//2:
    if s_[i] != s_[-1-i]:
        print('NO')
        f = 0
        break
    i += 1
if f == 1:
    print('YES')
```

Большое спасибо

Comment: Во втором решении перед циклом l равно нулю (потому что s_ — пустая строка нулевой длины) и i равно нулю, условие `i < l//2` не выполняется, и цикл не работает вообще

Comment: Как писал в своей книге Марк Лутц: "Не пишите на Python как на C". Не нужно проходиться циклом со счётчиком по перечисляемым множествам (iterable), к которым, в том числе, относятся строки. Используйте цикл `for ... in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы написал примерно так:

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    string = string.lower().replace(' ', '')
    rev_string = ''.join(reversed(string))

    return string == rev_string

my_str = 'a  b ba'
print('YES' if is_palindrome(my_str) else 'NO')
```

Это позволит переиспользовать при необходимости код проверки палиндрома, не будет менять никаких внешних переменных и выглядит достаточно понятно.

---

Небольшое объяснение происходящего:
Рекомендуется простые преобразования сцеплять в одно, т.е. вместо

```
string = string.lower()
string = string.replace(' ', '')
```

сразу писать

```
string = string.lower().replace()
```

это только упрощает чтение. Что происходит в этом случае, я думаю, понятно.

Функция `reversed` создаёт объект, который позволяет получить значения строки в обратном порядке, но формально не является строкой, поэтому требуется объединить символы, используя метод `join`.

---

Второй вариант можно записать так:

```py
def is_palindrome(string):
    string = string.lower().replace(' ', '')

    for i in range(len(string) // 2):
        if string[i] != string[-1-i]:
            return False
    return True
```

Стоит только иметь в виду, что в Python 2 вместо функции `range` почти всегда можно использовать `xrange`, которая не создаёт список в явном виде и потребляет меньше ресурсов. Цикл в таком случае будет выглядеть так:

```py
for i in xrange(len(string) // 2):
    ...
```

Также отмечу, что использование функций для разбиения функциональности упрощает чтение и понимание кода. Надеюсь, что вы вскоре освоите и это средство языка Python на пути к написанию правильного и красивого кода.

---

Небольшое замечание по исходному коду: значение `sys.argv[1]` -- это уже строка, так что дополнительное преобразование не требуется:

```py
import sys
# my_str = str(sys.argv[1])  # можно заменить на 
my_str = sys.argv[1]
```

Также рекомендую вам, если нет никаких зависимостей и дополнительных ограничений, использовать Python 3 для программирования. Вторая версия Python устарела.

Comment: Я только одного понять не могу: зачем такая сложная конструкция для проверки равенства исходной и перевёрнутой строки? Чем `string == rev_string` не угодил? Разве такое сравнение не будет более понятным при абсолютно аналогичном функционале?

Comment: что бы преподаватель сразу догадался, что @Anna не сама делала.

Comment: @fori1ton `rev_string` - это генератор. Придётся либо выполнить дополнительное преобразование, чтобы провека равенством сработала

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, ок, `string == ''.join(rev_string)` - всё ещё более читабельно. Или вы поставили перед собой задачу жёсткой экономии памяти?

Comment: @fori1ton Да, хороший вариант, внесу его в решение, а то и правда перемудрил

Answer (score 2):

Я взял бы первое решение и добавил туда одну строку

```
import sys

#my_str = str(sys.argv[1])
my_str = 'a b da'
my_str = my_str.lower()

my_str = my_str.replace(' ', '') # удалим пробелы!
rev_str = reversed(my_str)

if list(my_str) == list(rev_str):
   print("YES")
else:
   print("NO")
```

у этого решения есть один минус - оно портит исходную строку.

Comment: `print "YES" if str.lower() == reversed(filter(lambda x: not x.isspace(), str.lower())) else "NO"`

Исходная строка не затирается, учитываются все пробельные символы (а не только пробелы). Минус - теряется читаемость, увеличивается потребление памяти.

Comment: Добавила строку - и в результате ошибка 27\examples>test6.py "mystring1Gnir tsym"
 (most recent call last):
:\Python27\examples\test6.py", line 7, in <modul
r = my_str.replace(' ', '')
Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Уберите `s = s.split()`. Вы спокойно можете обращаться к отдельным символам строки через индекс (`s[i]`) не превращая строку в список.

Comment: @Anna - я проверил у себя с 2 и 3 питоном - все работает как нужно. Правда у меня странно ругнулось на комментарий, но я его удалил.